# Determining % of time above a certain value in a dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, graph

I have a dataset of voltages (Sampled every 500ms). Lets say it looks something like this (In an array):

```
0ms      -> 1.4v
500ms    -> 1.3v
1000ms   -> 1.2v
1500ms   -> 1.5v
2000ms   -> 1.3v
2500ms   -> 1.3v
3000ms   -> 1.2v
3500ms   -> 1.3v
```

Assuming the transition between readings is linear (IE: 250ms = 1.35v), how would I go about calculating the total % of time that the reading is above or equal to 1.3v?

I was initially going to just get % of values that are >= 1.3v (IE: 6/8 in sample array), however this only works if the angle between points is 45 degrees. I am assuming I have to do something like create a line from point 1 to point 2 and find the intercept with the base line (1.3v). Then do the same for point 2 and point 3 and find the distance between both intersects (Say 700ms) then repeat for all points and get as a % of total sample time.

**EDIT**

Maybe I wasn't clear when I initially asked. I need help with identifying how I can perform these calculations, IE: objects/classes that I can use to help me virtually graph these lines and perform these calculations or any 3rd party math packages that might offer these capabilities.

Comment: That seems like a sound approach to me.  Where is the programming angle?

Comment: @phoog I beg to differ - seems like he needs help with the implementation, not the algorith!

Comment: @EugenRieck fair enough -- and the question has been clarified.  So I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: For the sample data, I get an answer of (11/6)/3.5 or 52.38%.  Expressed in ms, it would be (1833 + 1/3)/3500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part is not to think in data points, but in intervals. Every interval (e.g. 0-500, 500-1000, ...) is one of three cases (starting with float variables `above` and `below` both 0):

- Trivial: Both start and end point are below your threshold - `below += 1`
- Trivial: Both start and end point are above your threshold - `above += 1`
- Interesting: One point is below, one above your threshold. Let's call the smaller value `min` and the higher value `max`. Now we do `above += (max-threshold)/(max-min)` and `below += (threshold-min)/(max-min)`, so we linearily distribute this interval between both states.

Finally normalize the results by dividing both `above` and `below` by the number of intervals. This will give you a pair of numbers, that represent the fractions, i.e. that add up to 1 modulo rounding errors. Ofcourse multiplication with 100 gives you the percentages.

**EDIT**

@phoog pointed out in the comment, that I did not mention an "equal" case. This is by design, as your question already contains that: You chose `>=` as a comparison, so I definitly ment to use the same comparison here.

Comment: You don't take into account the "or equal" bit.  The first case should be "both start and end point are below your threshold, or one point is below and the other equal to your threshold"; the second should be "both start and end point are above or equal to your threshold".

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem correctly, you can use a class like this to hold each entry:

```
    public class DataEntry
    {
        public DataEntry(int time, double reading)
        {
            Time = time;
            Reading = reading;
        }

        public int Time { get; set; }
        public double Reading { get; set; }
    }
```

And then the following link statement to get segments above 1.3:

```
        var entries = new List<DataEntry>()
        {
            new DataEntry(0, 1.4),
            new DataEntry(500, 1.3),
            new DataEntry(1000, 1.2),
            new DataEntry(1500, 1.5),
            new DataEntry(2000, 1.3),
            new DataEntry(2500, 1.3),
            new DataEntry(3000, 1.2),
            new DataEntry(3500, 1.3)
        };

        double totalTime = entries
            .OrderBy(e => e.Time)
            .Take(entries.Count - 1)
            .Where((t, i) => t.Reading >= 1.3 && entries[i + 1].Reading >= 1.3)
            .Sum(t => 500);

        var perct = (totalTime / entries.Max(e => e.Time));
```

This should give you the 500ms segments that remained above 1.3.